# How to identify class stereotypes for use case scenario?

Tags: uml, use-case, stereotype, use-case-diagram

How to identify class stereotypes for use case scenario?

I have my use case scenario. But Identifying class stereotypes means?

Comment: Class stereotypes has little to do with use case scenarios. Can you put your question in some broader context? So far if sounds like some sort of an excerpt from a homework.

Comment: https://imgur.com/b8EbV9G
check above link to half completed Use case scenario. Question is "Identify class stereotypes for the use case scenario". Can you give me example how to do it?

Comment: If you have more information about your question please edit the question and not add the additional information in the comments. But even with the additional information there is no way to answer that question in a way that makes sense. I'm guessing there must be some crucial information missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class stereotypes does not mean the UML term `stereotype` but to find "something that fits" in this context. So the class `Purchase` would come to mind here (re. your commented picture).

Comment: Can you tell me example for this. I dont know how to write/draw class stereotype for use case. This is my question "Identify class stereotypes for the use case scenario"

Comment: No. This is your homework. Start thinking why I said there must be a `Purchase` class and what it can do in context of this use case.

Comment: hello cal u tell me example please.